# JavaFx : how to split a string and also display the splitting character on the UI (":")

Tags: java, split, hyperlink

I have the following string to display on the UI. I want to highlight the url part of the string.
I used `.split(":", 2);` to split only at the first ":". However, I want that ":" to also be visible even after splitting.

```
String url = "welcome to:http://localhost:0000/stack_overflow/";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were to do it myself, I would not include the greeting part in the String url. I would have another string called greeting that has whatever you want the greeting to be, and a totally separate string for the url. This way, there is no issue with removing the colon, and you can also change the greeting to something else later on in a much cleaner way.

Other than `String.split(":");`, if you really need the greeting in the same string, you can just do `String greeting = url.substring(0, url.indexOf(":") + 1);` and that `String pureUrl = url.substring(url.indexOf(":") + 1);`. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Small correction: the second part should be `url.substring(url.indexOf(":")+1`

Comment: It is highly recommended: always test before posting.

Answer (score 0):

I almost sure the method .split() of String can not do that, but you always can do your own implementation.
Otherwise you can split then concat the split char (":") to every item of the array, or the needed one.

Comment: `.split(":", 2);` splits and removes just the first `:`